# Derivatives of Logarithmic functions

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Differentiate

$x^2 \ln(1+x^2) $

I simplified it till -

$2x^2 \ln(x) $

Then I differentiate -

$2x^2 (\dfrac{1}{x} (\dfrac{d}{dx} x) + \ln x (4x) $

$\dfrac{2x^2}{x} + 4x\ln x$

Where have I gone wrong ? Because the answer I am trying to achieve is

$\dfrac{2x^3}{1+x^2} + 2x\ln(1+x^2) $

Comment: Your simplification is wrong. You cannot just remove the 1 from the logarithm.

Comment: M. Winter is right, I think what you did is assuming that the logarithm was linear, i.e. $\ln(1+x^2)=\ln(1)+\ln(x^2)=\ln(x^2)$ but of course that is not true, if that were true the logarithm of every integer could be broke into a sum of logarithms of one and log would be 0 at every integer. In fact you can prove that if $f$ is linear then $f(x)=0$ iff. $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply product rule :

$$\frac{d(f(x) \cdot g(x))}{dx}=f'(x)\cdot g(x)+f(x)\cdot g'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your simplification is wrong: you can't do that with logarithms. Directly with the product rule:

$$\left(x^2\log(1+x^2)\right)'=2x\log(1+x^2)+\frac{2x^3}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2\ln(1+x^2))'=2x\ln(1+x^2)+x^2\cdot\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=2x\ln(1+x^2)+\frac{2x^3}{1+x^2}$$